# Spring 3.2.3 : activemq 5.5 dependency problems

Tags: spring, maven-2, activemq-classic

I'm trying to upgrade a project to spring 3.2.3, from spring 3.0.7.  I'm currently stuck on a problem with activemq dependencies and can't figure out what jar I need or is conflicting in the first place.  The following is my stacktrace

> org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Unable to create application
>   context for locations [classpath:producerServiceContext-test.xml]     at
>   org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:121)
>     at
>   org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:36)
>     at
>   org.unitils.core.util.AnnotatedInstanceManager.getInstanceImpl(AnnotatedInstanceManager.java:234)
>     at
>   org.unitils.core.util.AnnotatedInstanceManager.getInstance(AnnotatedInstanceManager.java:121)
>     at
>   org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.getApplicationContext(ApplicationContextManager.java:65)
>     at
>   org.unitils.spring.SpringModule.getApplicationContext(SpringModule.java:235)
>     at
>   org.unitils.spring.SpringModule$1.isApplicableFor(SpringModule.java:108)
>     at
>   org.unitils.database.transaction.impl.DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.getTransactionManagementConfiguration(DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.java:180)
>     at
>   org.unitils.database.transaction.impl.DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.startTransaction(DefaultUnitilsTransactionManager.java:96)
>     at
>   org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.startTransaction(DatabaseModule.java:410)
>     at
>   org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule.startTransactionForTestMethod(DatabaseModule.java:381)
>     at
>   org.unitils.database.DatabaseModule$DatabaseTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(DatabaseModule.java:535)
>     at
>   org.unitils.core.Unitils$UnitilsTestListener.beforeTestSetUp(Unitils.java:273)
>     at
>   org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$TestListenerInvokingMethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:151)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:95)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:61)
>     at
>   org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.access$000(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:44)
>     at
>   org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner$1.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:62)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
>     at
>   org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path
>   resource [producerServiceContext-test.xml]: Initialization of bean
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>     at
>   org.unitils.spring.util.ApplicationContextManager.createInstanceForValues(ApplicationContextManager.java:117)
>     ... 28 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: NULL     at
>   org.springframework.expression.TypedValue.(TypedValue.java:32)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.setRootObject(StandardEvaluationContext.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext.(StandardEvaluationContext.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:225)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:201)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     ... 37 more

The following are my activemq pom dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Furthermore I'm using the distribution bundle of spring 3.2.3.  I like to avoid copy pasting that one here since it are quite some dependencies and I rather keep this concise and to the point.

this is my applicationcontext that won't load up

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!--  lets create an embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
    <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>

    <!--  ActiveMQ destinations to use  -->
    <amq:queue id="destination" physicalName="org.apache.activemq.spring.Test.spring.embedded" />

    <!-- JMS ConnectionFactory to use, configuring the embedded broker using XML -->
    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false" />


    <!-- Spring JMS Template -->
    <bean id="fastJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <!-- lets wrap in a pool to avoid creating a connection per send -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <ref local="jmsFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="consumerJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="fastJmsProducer" class="com.emakina.truvo.ssls.fast.service.util.FastJmsProducer">
        <property name="template">
            <ref bean="fastJmsTemplate"></ref>
        </property>

        <property name="destination">
            <ref bean="destination" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="consumer" class="com.emakina.truvo.ssls.fast.service.util.SimpleFastJmsConsumer">
        <property name="template" ref="consumerJmsTemplate" />
        <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

If anyone came across the same integration problem I would really appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the dependency that was causing the problem.  Spring security is still managing an old version of it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

It seems that Spring-Security is bringing in spring-expression 3.0.7.  This caused problems for activemq to start it's broker since it uses classes from that lib.  I found the problem by putting a breakpoint on the NoSuchField exception, and look at the class it stopped in and what lib that class belonged to.  I hope this will help other people as well.

In my case I just had to add the dependency with the new spring version.